# Return a max value after aggregate ($sum) of array elements

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sum, max

as a beginner of NoSQL-Databases I have following problem in MongoDB:
My "scheme" looks like:

```js
Film document
{
"title": "film",
"type": "object",
"properties":{
 "id":{
  "type": "integer"
 },
 "title": {
  "type": "string"
 },
 "genre": {
  "type": "string"
 },
 "ratings":{
  "type": "array",
   "items": [
     {
     "type": "object",
     "properties": {
    "userId": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "rating": {
      "type": "number"
    }
   }
  }]
 }
}
}
```

With this queue, I get the right result, but not only one object.

```
db.film.aggregate( [
{ $unwind: "$ratings" },
{ $group: {
    _id: '$title', 
    SumRating: { $sum: '$ratings.rating' } 
} } , {$sort:{SumRating:-1}}]);
```

So my problem is to use the $max operator. I tried something but nothing worked fine for me. Does somebody has an idea how I need to use the operator to get only the movie with the highest/max rating?

Comment: How can you unwind ratings directly? From the input given ratings is present inside 'properties'.

Comment: add $limit:1 to your pipeline

Comment: db.film.aggregate( [
{ $unwind: "$ratings" },
{ $group: {
    _id: '$title', 
    SumRating: { $sum: '$ratings.rating' } 
} } , {$sort:{SumRating:-1}},{$limit:1}]);

Comment: Okay, it works, thank you! But with this statement, mongo have to $sum and sorting and only print the first one out. Is it not possible to $sum and select/print out the "highest" ($max) one without sorting?